# Pass PHP variable into Java Script function parameter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here's my javaScript function that shows a dialog box but only when the class `#dialog` its called in some div tag.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
          }
        });
   });

</script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="dialog" title="Download complete">
    <p>
      Your registration is complete, press ok to return to the previous page.
    </p>
   </div>
</body>
```

What i want to do its to show a message from a php string variable like this:

```
$message="Your registration is complete, press ok to return to the previous page.";
```

And on the JS function change the `#dialog` to a php variable `$message`.

I've tried several ways, it's very confusing. Please give me a hand.

Comment: Save the variable in a hidden field and get that value using javascript, when you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

A common way to do that is to set a JS variable on the page that contains the PHP data and then read it with your script. Assuming you're not using a framework with templates that makes this easier, you could write some PHP like :

```
<php
echo "<script>MyApp.message=$message</script>";
?>
```

And then in your JS, you can access it like :

```
<script>
  $(function() {
        // replace this with whatever logic you need to display the message
        console.log(MyApp.message);
   });

</script>
```

You just need to make sure that the second script runs after the first script has been loaded.

Comment: The thing is im going to use a lot of dialog boxes in my website.Here's my other script:


`<?php
 function alerta($texto="",$redirect=""){
  print("<Script language=javascript>");
  if($texto!="")
   print("alert(\"$texto\");");
  if($redirect!="")
   print("window.location=\"$redirect\";");
  print("</script>");
 }
?>`

All i have to do is call my function with the text i want:

`alerta("Your registration is comlete","index.html");`

I want to do this with this JS function.

Comment: You can call whatever you want from JS. You just need to set the PHP content you want to use in JS vars first as in my example above. If you have many messages, you can easily turn MyApp.message into a JS object with each message having a key you use in the JS. So your JS can call something like alert(MyApp.message['warning']); It's generally a bad idea to try to actually generate your JS scripts from PHP like you're doing in the example you just gave.

Comment: I figured it out but thank for trying to help anyways